# Finding the combinations of n-spaced actions to a specific result

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic, combinations

Given the following statement:

2 players each have 100HP

They can both attack using -2HP, -5HP or -7HP attacks

They can attack an unlimited times in a row

A player loses when his HP is <= 0

I need to find the number of situations where player A wins over player B.

Here's my code so far :

```
import itertools

win = 0
for j in itertools.product(range(1, 7), repeat=100):
    a = 100
    b = 100
    for i in j:
        if (i == 1):
            b -= 2
        elif (i == 2):
            b -= 5
        elif (i == 3):
            b -= 7
        elif (i == 4):
            a -= 2
        elif (i == 5):
            a -= 5
        elif (i == 6):
            a -= 7
        if b <= 0 and a > 0:
            win += 1
            if (win % 1000000 == 0):
                print(j)
                print(win)
            break
        if a <= 0:
            break
```

I've chosen 100 repeats for the extreme case where both player A and B hits with 2HP attacks only.

Of course, this would take a huge time to compute.

I need to find a faster algorithm.

Comment: Can you create a data structure `ways_a_wins[a_hp][b_hp]` and populate it for the 10201 pairs of values `0 <= a_hp <= 100` and `0 <= b_hp <= 100`?

Comment: Great idea! But I'm not sure how to fill that structure, wouldn't it be the same computation in the end?

Comment: There are multiple ways to fill that structure.  Look up dynamic programming.  But however you do it, filling it just requires doing 10,000 computations.  Rather than having to find all of the ways to get to half hitpoints, then repeatedly tracing all the ways to get from there to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using DP to fill a matrix s.t. the value in position (i,j) represents the count of ways of losing i health in j moves

arr[i,j] = arr[i-2, j-1] + arr[i-5, j-1] + arr[i-7, j-2], only considering prior non-winning values (so i < 100 in the prior values).

initialize arr[0,0] = 1

We'll populate this in order of increasing j then i, starting with j=1

Values at indices (i, j) for i >= 100 represent the count of ways of getting a winning score in j moves. This will go up to 106, which is the max winning score (99+7). Similarly, for i < 100 these represent the count of ways of getting a losing score in j moves.

For each number of moves, count the number of ways of winning and of losing in that many moves. We'll be able to lose in 0-49 moves, and able to win in 15-50 moves.

Now, for every winning score, for every losing score, we need to calculate the way these counts can be interleaved. Say we have a winning score in j moves and a losing score in k moves. This is choose(j + k - 1, k).

The -1 is because the last move (the winning move) must be from the winning set. Think of this as choosing the k positions of losing moves out of the j+k-1 possibilities to cover every arrangement that ends with a winning move.

Final answer: For every way of winning in j moves and losing in k moves, we add (count of j-move wins) * (count of k-move losses) * choose(j+k-1, k) to our total.

E.g. matrix & wins/losses subtotals for max hp of 10:

```
> count_wins([2,5,7], 10)
hp loss: 0      1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|
hp loss: 1      0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|
hp loss: 2      0|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|
hp loss: 3      0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|
hp loss: 4      0|   0|   1|   0|   0|   0|
hp loss: 5      0|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|
hp loss: 6      0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   0|
hp loss: 7      0|   1|   2|   0|   0|   0|
hp loss: 8      0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|
hp loss: 9      0|   0|   2|   3|   0|   0|
hp loss: 10     0|   0|   1|   0|   0|   1|
hp loss: 11     0|   0|   0|   3|   4|   0|
hp loss: 12     0|   0|   2|   2|   0|   0|
hp loss: 13     0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|
hp loss: 14     0|   0|   1|   4|   3|   0|
hp loss: 15     0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|
hp loss: 16     0|   0|   0|   2|   3|   0|
loss:           1|   3|   5|   4|   1|   0|
win:            0|   0|   4|  11|  11|   3|
=> 4078 (ways of winning)
```

For max hp of 3 I get:

```
count_wins([2,5,7], 3)
loss:           1|   1|   0|
win:            0|   2|   3|
=> 13 (ways of winning)
```

13 ways for A to win. These are:

```
A's moves: [[5], [7], [2,2], [2,5], [2,7]]
B's moves: [[], [2]]
```

Each of the 5 ways A can win can either be with no B moves (5), with a single initial B move (5), or with a single B move between the two A moves in the 3 cases this applies (3). Our total is 13, as expected based on the algorithm above.

For count_wins([2,5,7], 100) I get a final answer of:

102,033,940,458,046,779,283,026,415,918,520,992,505,663

Comment: The matrix could be more space-efficient via a hash, but we're dealing with small enough numbers that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Note that these numbers get big. The sum of the k-moves column is 3^k.

Comment: Mistake.  You are counting ways to end at 0.  In fact you can end < 0.  So the (1, 1) entry should be 3 because there are 3 ways that a wins.

Comment: @btilly The 1,1 entry is the number of ways to have lost 1 health in 1 move, which is 0. I count ways to get up to 106 hp loss. In one move you can lose 2, 5, or 7 health, so these rows have a count of 1 in the 1 column and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: Though 0,0 should be 1 since there is one way to lose in 0 moves.

Comment: To be clear, B can attack at anytime too, so we need to consider all those possibilities too. Eg. with 5HP: A attacks 2 B attacks 2 B attacks 2 A attacks 3 is a possibility. Unsure if this answer considers this.

Comment: @MaximeB It does. The matrix shows all ways of getting a certain score in a certain number of moves. Then we take all winning scores (A's) and losing scores (B's), and all ways of interleaving them with the only restriction that the last move be A's (so that B can't play a move after A wins).

Comment: @MaximeB For 5 hp, I see 48 ways that A can win.

Comment: That's the correct answer ! Thank you so much !

Comment: @MaximeB Can you share where the problem comes from?

Comment: It is a French recruitment agency sharing a 5 enigmas game, and this was the fifth.

Comment: @btilly I'm not sure what I wrote that you misinterpreted; I attempted to clarify my answer so my approach is clear.

Comment: @Dave I just assumed that you were implementing the more obvious approach that I suggested, and saw that the data structure was wrong for that.  I was wrong, you just had a different approach.  I posted my approach as well so that you can compare.

Answer (score 1):

For any dp problem, it is usually easiest to write the solution as a recursive function and then cache.

Here is that solution

```
def ways_for_a_to_win (a_hp, b_hp, moves=None, cache=None):
    if moves is None:
        moves = [2, 5, 7]
    if cache is None:
        cache = {}

    if a_hp <= 0:
        return 0
    elif b_hp <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        if (a_hp, b_hp) not in cache:
            answer = 0
            for move in moves:
                answer += ways_for_a_to_win(a_hp - move, b_hp, moves, cache)
                answer += ways_for_a_to_win(a_hp, b_hp - move, moves, cache)
            cache[(a_hp, b_hp)] = answer
        return cache[(a_hp, b_hp)]

print(ways_for_a_to_win(100, 100))
```

Comment: @Dave I guess I find it obvious because this is always my first approach.  Write a recursive function, memoize.